# Como ajustar tela de acordo com o teclado virtual do Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragment

Gostaria de saber como faço pra redimensionar a tela de acordo com a exibição ou não do teclado Virtual do Android, estilo a tela inicial do Evernote, que quando aparece o teclado a imagem diminui e quando o teclado desativa, a imagem superior expande novamente.

Meu código se encontra da seguinte forma:

Na activity_login.xml encontra-se o AppBarLayout, o qual quero expandir ou diminuir e o trecho está da seguinte forma:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/ablLogin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

//aqui fica o ImageView

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Estou trabalhando com Fragments, e está correto tudo certo, e coloquei a logica na fragment pois ela sera exibixa na tela inteira caso ativa o teclado e coloquei dessa forma.

FragmentLogin:

```
private View view;

public View onCreateView{

view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) ((View) (view.getParent().getParent().getParent())).findViewById(R.id.ablLogin);

            Rect r = new Rect();

            view.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
            int screenHeight = view.getRootView().getHeight();

            // r.bottom is the position above soft keypad or device button.
            // if keypad is shown, the r.bottom is smaller than that before.
            int keypadHeight = screenHeight - r.bottom;

            Log.v(tag, "view.getParent() = " + view.getParent().getParent().getParent().getClass());

            if (appBarLayout == null) {
                Log.v(tag, "appBarLayout eh null");
            } else {
                Log.v(tag, AppBarLayout.class.getName());
            }

            if(appBarLayout!=null){
                if (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15) { // 0.15 ratio is perhaps enough to determine keypad height.
                    // keyboard is opened
                    Log.v(tag, "Aberto:  " + keypadHeight);
                    appBarLayout.setExpanded(false, true);
                } else {
                    // keyboard is closed
                    Log.v(tag, "Fechado " + keypadHeight);
                    appBarLayout.setExpanded(true, true);
                }
            }

        }
    });

return view;
}
```

O que acontece é que quando ativa o teclado o setExpended não roda, e não aponta erro nenhum, só que quando minimizo a tela de login no android e depois maximizo, ela faz o que eu quero.

Como resolver isso?

Comment: Então você já tem a solução para maximizar e minimizar a imagem? Só que ela apenas funciona se abrir o teclado e sair e entrar no App,  certo?

Comment: Exatamente isso colega @Luiz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro do seu `AndroidManifest.xml` adicione a seguinte propriedade dentro da `<activity>` que você quer adicionar esse atributo:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: Infelizmente não resolveu, continua a mesma coisa

Comment: Tente colocar `android:windowSoftInputMode=adjustPan|adjustResize`